# On checkout page CVV field is missing

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment

I'm using magento 1.9.2.4 with Authorize.net and PayPal. How to add CVV field to Magento checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Authorize.net

You able to enable cvv from magento `Admin->System->Configuration->Payment Methods->Expand selected Payment Method accordion` their should be a option `Credit Card Verification` this value should be `Yes`.

Screen shot

http://www.amanweb.in/stackexchange/ccv.jpg

Comment: I followed your advice and then flushed that page cache, but it did not solved the problem.

Comment: Which payment method you are using?

Comment: We are using Authorize.net and PayPal.